# Closing a form that is created in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have been searching for an answer to my particular problem for a while with no success.

I have a task in my program that takes a few seconds and I want to show a new form while that task is being done. The new form has a loadingbar and some text.

I need to show the new form parallel to the task otherwise the task will not start untill I close the new form.

This is the solution I have now:

```
private void loadingBar()
{
    frmLoading frm = new frmLoading("Please wait while the database is being backed up", "This might take several days.");
    frm.ShowDialog();  

}

public void Backup()
{
    Thread load = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingBar));
    load.Start();

    ///Execute a task.

    load.Abort(); 
}
```

So, this works OK but my question is: Wouldn't it be better to close the the form "frm" in the load-thread to make it stop?

Comment: Treat it like a progress bar works.  Run the "process" as a background thread subservient to the form you want to show.  Then call that form from the "Main" thread.  The Main thread will lock with your loading form showing, while the loading form runs something as a background thread.  That way the loading form itself can track the process and close itself once its over.

Comment: @Dave Why not just use a `backgroundWorker`?
Also - You might want to consider placing that code for the Thread in a `Using()` statement, this will then dispose itself on completion.

Comment: This is fundamentally the wrong thing to do.  There are several very nasty failure modes to displaying UI on a worker thread.  You need to do this the other way around, display the "loading" window on the UI thread, perform the backup on a worker thread.

Comment: I tried to put in a loading dialog using this exact method... ends in ThreadAbortExceptions about 20% of the time.

Comment: I am facing this exact same problem.But I need to show and hide an Already existing form that i have designed using separate thread (not creating in using the thread as above). what is the approach to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this a few ways...

1 - You could do as BendEg suggested and invoke you frmClose once you are ready

Something like;

```
Invoke(new Action(Close));
```

or

```
Invoke(new Action(() => frmMain.Close()));
```

2 - Or you could simply use a background worker;

The simplest way to demonstrate this would be to add a BackgroundWorker to your form, and use the events provided;

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    MessageBox.Show(@"Please wait while the database is being backed up", @"This might take several days.");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Running"); //Execute a task
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Ended"); //Dispose of any objects you'd like (close yor form etc.)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the form on Class-Level and later close it with an invoke.
[MSDN-Windows Forms Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

Like this:

```
    public class Class1
{
    private Form myForm;

    public Class1()
    {
        myForm = new Form();
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        // ===================================================
        // Do Some Work...
        // ===================================================

        myForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Hide));
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        myForm.Hide();
    }

    public void Backup()
    {
        myForm.ShowDialog();

        Thread load = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomeWork));
        load.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work for you.

```
void YourMethod()
{
     WaitForm wf = new WaitForm();
     Invoke(new PleaseWaitDelegate(Launch),wf);
     bool val = BoolMethodDoWork();
     Invoke(new PleaseWaitDelegate(Close), wf);
                if(val)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Damn!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
delegate void PleaseWaitDelegate(Form form);
        void Launch(Form form)
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(()=> form. ShowDialog()).Start();
        }

        void Close(Form form)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you (if i understood you right):

```
                Parallel.Invoke(() => somemethod(), () =>
                {
                    someothertaskmethod();
                });
```

I placed methods as example to demonstrate 2 tasks running.

You nee to use the proper using statement `using System.Threading.Tasks;`